# Giving background color to a svg graph till the region covered by specific line

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg, time-series

Below is my D3 graph, code to render this graph is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<svg width="960" height="200"></svg>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://mcaule.github.io/d3-timeseries/src/d3_timeseries.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://mcaule.github.io/d3-timeseries/src/d3_timeseries.js"></script>
<script>

  var data =    [{
                    "timestamp": "2017-06-23T19:03:00-07:00",
                    "a_1": 21.100729166695746,
                    "a_2": 13.862652074746523
                },
                {
                    "timestamp": "2017-06-23T19:03:10-07:00",
                    "a_1": 21.09999908563894,
                    "a_2": 13.865705100895076
                },
                {
                    "timestamp": "2017-06-23T19:03:20-07:00",
                    "a_1": 21.099269029842795,
                    "a_2": 13.965687962747438
                },
                {
                    "timestamp": "2017-06-23T19:03:30-07:00",
                    "a_1": 21.098538999306424,
                    "a_2": 14.072341340713344
                },
                {
                    "timestamp": "2017-06-23T19:03:40-07:00",
                    "a_1": 21.097808994028977,
                    "a_2": 14.105108226640267
                },
                {
                    "timestamp": "2017-06-23T19:03:50-07:00",
                    "a_1": 21.097079014009566,
                    "a_2": 14.431892151709313
                },
                {
                    "timestamp": "2017-06-23T19:04:00-07:00",
                    "a_1": 21.096349059247324,
                    "a_2": 13.827938924324112
                },
                {
                    "timestamp": "2017-06-23T19:04:10-07:00",
                    "a_1": 21.09561912974137,
                    "a_2": 13.90099860030143
                }]

data.map(function(ele,index){
    ele.timestamp = new Date(ele.timestamp);
});

var chart = d3.timeseries();

chart.addSerie(data.slice(0,3), {
    x: 'timestamp',
    y: 'a_1'
  }, {
    interpolate: 'linear',
    color: "#505050",
    label: "value_1"
  });

  chart.addSerie(data.slice(4), {
    x: 'timestamp',
    y: 'a_2'
  }, {
    interpolate: 'linear',
    color: "#A9A9A9",
    label: "value_2"
  });

chart.width(900)

chart("body")

</script>
```

I have described my problem in below image:

[Need to have some background color the first series added in graph, couldn't figure out how to do that.Please suggest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFFvI.png)

Comment: Without posting any code it is really hard to tell. Generally if you want to shade a part of the graphic though, what I've seen done is to add another svg element as a container(rect, circle, etc) and apply a color to its fill property.

Comment: *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers"*.

Comment: @peinearydevelopment , check edits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best you can do with this library is to add to your data an extra `baseline` value for each point that is always `0`. Then you can draw a diff that will fill the area between the baseline and your values with `color`:

```
.addSerie(
    data.slice(0,60),
    { x: 'date', y: 'n', diff: 'baseline' },
    { interpolate: 'linear', color: "#a6cee3", label:"value" }
)
```

The `data.slice(0,60)` should be taken as an example, where the background would be restricted to the first 60 data points. You should choose all data points you want to draw a background below, and leave all others out of this series.

Comment: This clearly seems to be working, but in background it takes some default color it seems, how to change this color?

Comment: it seems to be covering only the region below the line, but not till . the length of y axis, how to do this?

Comment: check the image I've put in the question

Comment: if i give value like 10 or 50; it do covers region above the line but not below the line. please suggest